# Can Xcode support multiple layouts?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I made an Android app I used about 100 different classes, each with a different layout file, stored in xml format.
I am trying to write a similar app in Xcode but wonder if it is possible to have so many different views on a storyboard. Certainly the layout would be complicated.
Or is there some other approach to this problem?

Comment: you can create as many views you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have many views/controllers per storyboard file, and you can have many storyboard files as well. And then, there are still the good old nib/xib files, of which you can also have as many as you like.

I suggest to structure your UI into sensible chunks. From my experience it is no fun to work with giant storyboard files - they become hard to navigate, and the dependency on that one huge file can become a burden.

Comment: Thanks. This seems the way to go. I will investigate

Answer (score 1):

In ios XIB() is very much similar to android XML file which provide UI. there are some strong features that are introduce by apple - autolayout and size class in which a single XIB can be used for different different screen size and it can automatically handle different screen modes (landscape and portrait)

Answer (score 0):

You can lay out your interface in as many nib files as you like, and load them programmatically. Of course, storyboard references now allow you to split a complex interface across multiples files too.